# How do I pass a Date object to a custom JSP tag defined with a tag file?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

My real goal is to have a simple tag that will automatically format dates a specific way (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm). If we need to change it in the future, it would be nice to not have to have  all over the place, needing to be updated to the new format.

As it stands, I do not understand why the date argument I am passing to my tag is being interpreted as a String.

Here is my simple tag (date.tag) file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ attribute name="value" type="java.util.Date" rtexprvalue="false" required="true"%>
${value} ${value.class}
```

And here is my jsp file that I'm using to test it.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="me" uri="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<jsp:useBean id="now" scope="application" class="java.util.Date" />
<me:date value="${now}" />
```

The output is: Fri Jul 12 10:36:05 MST 2013 class java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `rtexprvalue="true"` in your attribute declaration.

Comment: That didn't see to resolve it. When adding the formatDate tag below the value and value.class expressions, I get "Error 500: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert Fri Jul 12 10:36:05 MST 2013 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date "

Answer (score 0):

As JB Nizet said: first you're missing `rtexprvalue="true"`, also the attribute "uri" should be changed to "tagdir".

In the tag file I didn't do anything but output the values of "value" and its type:

```
<%@ attribute name="value"  rtexprvalue="true" required="true" type="java.util.Date" %>
${value}
<%
out.print(jspContext.getAttribute("value").getClass());
%>
```

The result was : `Sat Jul 13 02:22:31 GMT+02:00 2013 class java.util.Date`

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of JB Nizet and a.u.r., I was able to use `${value['class']}` to get the output "class java.util.Date"

I also tried `<fmt:formatDate value="${value}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>` and got the expected formatted date.

I am using Tomcat-7.0.42 and jstl-1.2.